# How to delete/update ODBC - System DNS - Database

Tags: windows, odbc, pervasive

How can I update or delete the highlighted **Database** in the screenshot below? I have searched the Registry and cannot find it anywhere. It is configured incorrectly and needs to be recreated or updated.

[image: ODBC System DNS - screenshot]

Comment: I think updating databases (like create/deted), should be done using the [Pervasive Control Center](https://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv13/index.html#page/uguide/OpenSQLDoc.htm). After making the change, it should be available in odbcad32.exe

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Pervasive Control Center did the trick.